# Given $\frac{y+a}{x+a}=b$, is there a solution for $\frac{x}{y}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an expression of the form:
$$\frac{y+a}{x+a}=b$$
I know there is an infinity of solutions for x and y, but what I'm looking for is a solution for x/y, unique or otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$ \dfrac {y+a}{x + a} = b \implies y + a = b \cdot (x+a) = bx + ba. $$I hope you can finish from here and see that the solution for the ratio is not unique.

Comment: From your friend +1